# CSS max content width in large screens (purecss)

Tags: html, css

I've a problem with my webpage which looks good on smartphones and tablets. But on desktop screens the content stretch out over the full page width.
I use pure-css frame.
[example link](http://83.163.140.140//web2016/spa_wellness_arrangementen/vriendinnendag_wellness_arrangement.html)

What I want that the grids don't stretch out over the whole page when it's shown on a wide desktop page

In my css I've some breakpoints for the media screen.
The whole page is wrapped like this

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="pure-g"> 
     <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-lg-1-3"> ...... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to make a smaller width on largepages with the  pure-u-lg-1-3, but besides that this doesn't work, I doubt if this is the solution.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 100px }
}
```

What i want is that my content on large media screens above 800px is limited in width. 
How can I set the content of my page on max 600px (actually like almost every webpage do this)

Comment: `@media (min-width: 800px) {...}` Any resolutions above 800px will apply the styles you declare in this breakpoint; here you can declare a `max-width` rule to restrain your content for a given selector (or class) to a specified width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mate,

Try the below stylesheet and let me know whether it is working or not.

```css
/*Using media to set the style If screen is bigger than 800px*/
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 600px;/*Limit max-width to 600px*/
    margin: 0 auto;/*Centering this container*/
  }
}
```